# Salesforce CTI adapter with Amazon Connect custom CCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, salesforce, amazon-connect, salesforce-service-cloud

I am trying to implement Amazon Connect CTI adapter for Salesforce with a custom CCP UI.
I have followed this guide to successfully implement this.
https://amazon-connect.github.io/amazon-connect-salesforce-cti/docs/lightning/installation/01-installation

I also need to get the real time transcription working with this CTI adapter. I followed this guide which creates a custom CCP panel with real time transcription built in.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/contact-center/provide-call-sentiment-analytics-to-agents-using-real-time-contact-analysis-segment-streams-in-amazon-connect-contact-lens/

But I am not able to bring both together. When I change the salesforce SSO's destination url to the custom CCP URL, it shows up in the popup window(SSO authentication popup) but after that the traditional CCP panel shows up in the Salesforce softphone.

I am not sure where I need to update the custom CCP URL.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Is it about SSO or real-time transcription? Those are two different things but you've mentioned both. Try to focus on the thing that is not working, describe what you did, what you expected to happen, and what happened instead. Remove unnecessary details.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment the question is not very clear, but I will give it a go anyway.
I had a quick look at the [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/contact-center/provide-call-sentiment-analytics-to-agents-using-real-time-contact-analysis-segment-streams-in-amazon-connect-contact-lens/) you mentioned and I noticed that they didn't include a step to whitelist the custom CCP at Amazon Connect. Make sure the URL of the deployed app is whitelisted as described in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/app-integration.html).

Answer (score 0):

In order to customise the softphone that gets embedded in SalesForce there are a few steps.

First you need to create a VisualForce page to display your custom softphone. Once that is done then you need to update the CTI Adapter URL for The AC Lightning Adapter. To do this you have to go into `Service Setup` and then go to  `Channels->Phone->OpenCTI->CallCenters` and edit the AC Lightning Adapter.

[image: Channels->Phone->OpenCRI->CallCenters]

In the adapter you set the `CTI Adapter URL` to your VisualForce page. You may be able to set this directly to the url for your custom softphone. I've never tried that. My customisation has been cloning the `AC_LightningAdapter` VisualForce page and adding to it, so it calls other VF pages that include necessary scripts.

Note that at the very least you lose the CPP Overlay (the flyout tab that displays attached data and custom actions) from the softphone, as the VisualForce component that provides this is not global and can't be called from a custom VisualForce page.

Additionally, if you set the CTI Adapter URL to an external page it is possible that all the CTI Flows will stop working. Again I haven't tried this so not sure what would happen or exactly how the Adapater interacts with everything else.

Good luck :)